# Searching through multiple tables at once (Linq to SQL)?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have a couple tables that are kind of unrelated - id like to search through both of them and create a type that i can sift through later

something like this doesnt work

```
var results = from dog in _dataContext.Dogs  
                      where dog.Name.Contains(search)  

                      from catin _dataContext.Cats  
                      where cat.Name.Contains(search)  

                      select new AnimalSearchResults  
                                  {  
                                      Dog = dog,  
                                      Cat = cat  
                                  };  

        return results;
```

I basically want to create a list of "AnimalSearchResults" that contains all dogs and all cats that have that name

Whats the best way to do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other workaround would be to have the class *Cat* and the class *Dog* derivate the same base class, which would then carry the name.

Here's an example

```
public class Pet
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class Dog : Pet {...} 
public class Cat : Pet {...}
// I assume each classes have their singularity;
```

In your DataContext Object, create a GetPets() method, like this one :

```
public IEnumerable<Pet> GetPets()
{
    return Cats.Cast().Union( Dogs.Cast() );
}
```

Then use LINQ on the Pets in the DataContext.

```
var results =
    (from p in _dataContext.GetPets()
     where p.Name.Contains(search)
     select p);
```

This code would be more scalable, especially if u have more than 2 derivated classes.

{enjoy}

Comment: Then you could have `public class Unicorn : Pet {...}`

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you want to [Union the two results](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386993.aspx) so your basic query would be something like:

```
var results = (from dog in _dataContext.Dogs  
                      where dog.Name.Contains(search))
                      .Union
                      (from cat in _dataContext.Cats  
                      where cat.Name.Contains(search));
```